# Can an inner measure be written in terms of an outer measure?

Tags: measure-theory

Consider the outer measure
$$
\mu^{\star} \colon 2^{X} \longrightarrow [0,\infty]\colon A \longmapsto \inf\Big\{\sum_{n \geq 1} \mu(A_n) \colon A \subseteq \bigcup_{n \geq 1}A_n, A_n \in \mathcal{S} \text{ for all } n \geq 1\Big\}
$$
induced by a premeasure $\mu \colon \mathcal{S} \rightarrow [0,\infty]$ on a semiring $\mathcal{S}$.

Now let $A \subseteq X$ and $S \in \mathcal{S}$ with $A \subseteq S$ and set
$$
f(A) := \mu^{\star}(S) - \mu^{\star}(S \setminus A).
$$
I want to show that the value $f(A)$ does not depend on the set $S$. That is, if $S' \in \mathcal{S}$ with $A \subseteq S'$, then $f(A) = \mu^{\star}(S') - \mu^{\star}(S' \setminus A)$. My idea was to define the "inner measure"
$$
\mu_{\star}(A) : = \sup\Big\{\sum_{n \geq 1} \mu(A_n) \colon  \bigcup_{n \geq 1}A_n \subseteq A, A_n \in \mathcal{S} \text{ for all } n \geq 1\Big\}.
$$
Now I think it seems natural that one must have $f(A) = \mu_{\star}(A)$ (and hence $f(A)$ is indpendent of $S$). How can I formally prove this?

**REMARK.** Maybe it suffices to define 
$$
\mu_{\star}(A) : = \sup\big\{\mu(B) \colon  B \subseteq A, B \in \mathcal{S} \big\}
$$
and prove that $\mu_{\star}(A)  = f(A)$.